# Match inner pattern. Multiline

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have:

```
%{ lorem ipsum dolor 
   sit %{hello
           world}%
   amet}%
```

I want:

```
 hello
   world
```

That is, I want to keep the inner `%{...}%` of any number of nesting `%{...}%`s that may or may not span multiple lines.

Is there a sed or awk way?

Comment: Is it possible that there will be multiple `%{...}%` blocks that you need to capture? Or is it certain that there will just be the one?

Comment: @ruakh multiple blocks are possible but even the "just-one" case will help.

Comment: can you count on the prefix `sit` (per your example)? Good luck.

Comment: Your example hints at the requirement of deleting columns from the input. The relationship between `hello` and `world` remains at two spaces, but it's moved as a unit to column zero. You're manipulating whitespace in the %{ %} block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed` command:

```
sed -n -r 'H; ${g; s/([^}]|\}[^%])*%\{//; s/\}%([^%]|%[^{])*//; p}'
```

will gather the entirety of the input into the pattern space, then remove `...%{` (taking care to ensure that the `...` doesn't contain `}%`) and `}%...` (taking care to ensure that the `...` doesn't contain `%{`), and then print the result. So it's suitable for the case where you need just one block. The case with multiple blocks is trickier, but I'll think about it further, and update this answer if I get that working well.

Note that `-r` (to support Extended Regular Expressions, instead of Basic ones) is a GNU extension to `sed`, so if you're using a non-GNU `sed` that doesn't support it, let me know.

---

**Edited to add:** O.K., here's a version that supports multiple blocks:

```
sed -n -r 'H; ${g; s/^([^}]|\}[^%])*%\{//; s/\}%([^%]|%[^{])*$//; s/\}%([^%]|%[^{])*([^}]|\}[^%])*%\{/\n/g; p}'
```

It uses essentially the same approach as the previous, except that it only removes `...%{` at start-of-input and `}%...` at end-of-input, and that after it's done that, it proceeds to remove all instances of `}%...%{` that do not contain `%{...}%`, replacing them with a newline.

Comment: Thanks, I can use this as a start. In general, I want every `%{...}%` block that doesn't contain an other `%{...}%` block, where `%{...}%`s can be arbitrarily nested and formatted.

Answer (score 1):

The AWK way:

```
gawk '
/%{/ {
    match($0,/%{.*/)
    text=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
}
!/% {/ && !/}%/ {
    text=text "\n" $0
}
/}%/ {
    match($0,/}%/)
    text=text "\n" substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    print text
    exit
}'
```

This won't work if there's more than one {% or %} in the same line. In this case you need minor modification - use array in the match command.

Answer (score 1):

One possible TXR way:

Simply scan the input freeform (as one big line) collecting matches for a regular expression into the variable `wanted` which gets implicitly collected into a list called `wanted`.

Then spit out the pieces, chopping two characters from the head and tail of each.

```
$ txr -c '@(freeform)
@(coll)@{wanted /\%{(~(.*(\%{|}\%).*))}\%/}@(end)
@(output)
@(rep)@{wanted [2..-2]}@(end)
@(end)' -
asdf asdf %{
  %{ asdf
asdf             
}% %{boo}% }%
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
 asdf
asdf 
boo
```

The regex `~` operator means complement. The variable `wanted` captures text which consists of `%{` followed by the longest matching string which does **not** contain `%{` or `}%` as a substring, followed by `%}`. TXR regex supports complement, intersection, difference. We have to write `\%` character because `%` is the non-greedy zero-or-more operator.

The output for the example given in the question is:

```
hello
           world
```

rather than

```
hello
  world
```

Author didn't clarify if that is really needed. This complicates the problem because `%{hello` occurs somewhere in the middle of the line, and so we must know the column position of the `h` in `hello` in order to know that the `w` in `world` is two spaces over.